# Sending unlimited requests to a PHP file

Tags: php, ajax

Wondering if infinity requests to a PHP script can overload a website. What do you think?

Comment: It depends on your HOST: RAM, PROCESSOR, etc...

Comment: Why the down votes? Trying to understand how the sever works..

Comment: @Akam not really... infinity is sufficiently large enough to bypass all of those factors - and cause problems.

Comment: @NicholasPickering: yes I knew, even the bandwidth is a factor, nothing can handle infinity :)

Comment: @AdamGold your edit is likely to cause MORE downvotes - why are you trying to crash a server?

Comment: @NicholasPickering he's load testing his own server, which should be OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that it handles an AJAX request doesn't really matter. It's the same with the fact that a PHP scripts sends the request - it does not matter that it *comes* from a PHP script. So your question basically is: "Does my server go down if a PHP scripts is called very often?" and this only depends on the Hardware and Installation of your Server.

Comment: What if the PHP script that is being called inserts a new row to the database each time? Isn't there a limit?

Comment: again: depends on the hardware and installation. At some point in time, the harddrive has no space left. In a way this happens everytime a webpage is called since webserver often have log-files where they create an entry.

Comment: In today's servers, is there any chance of crashing in that scenario?

Comment: I've seen it happen that because of bad server configuration some program filled up the harddrive with log information. So: yes there is a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Try apache bench... `ab -n 10000 -c 1000`

Answer (score 0):

Use **[ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html)** if you have access to a command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are bench testing your Apache server for a particular configuration you need to measure the number of concurrent requests vs the response time.

It makes little difference if the server is able to handle X number of concurrent requests if the response time is too long. The is because users are impatient and likely to just move on.